# Find the general solution of the differential equation $9y^{(3)} + 11y'' + 4y' − 14y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I began this problem by first writing the characteristic polynomial: $$9r^{3} + 11r^{2} + 4r − 14 = 0$$
Solving this equation reveals the roots: $$r = \frac {7}{9}, -1 + i, -1 - i$$
Now because we have one real and two imaginary roots, our solution will be of the form: $$ y = c_1 e^{r_1 t} + c_2 e^{λt} \cos {μt} + c_ 3e^{λt} \sin {μt} = c_1 e^{ \frac {7t}{9}} + c_2 e^{-t} \cos {t} + c_3 e^{-t} \sin {t}$$
To find the general form, I just extrapolated from the forms I know for second order differential equations, so I am not sure if this is the correct way to solve this problem. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: You should correct the title you dont have $y^3$ but $y'''$

Comment: Your answer is fine except you need arbitrary coefficients $c_1, c_2, c_3$ in front of each term of your solution.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @Aryadeva.

Comment: It has been fixed @coffeemath. Thank you for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: You're very welcome

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Thanks for that! In general, can I extrapolate from second order forms for any higher orders as well?

Comment: Yes, the same method works for linear homegeneous ODEs of any order.